# Document Library - show checked out date in UI

Tags: document-library

In a document library it is possible to show the "Checked Out To" field to determine who has a file checked out - is it possible to show when it was checked out so you can easily find 'Forgotten' checkouts?

The object model has a [CheckedOutDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.checkedoutdate.aspx) property - any way to surface this to the UI, preferably without code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If '*surfacing to the UI*' == '*show in list view*' then '*you are out of luck*'

CheckedOutDate is SPFile property and can't be surfaced in list view. There is no such field in document library nor in Document Content Type.

Without using some code I don't see how it can be done manually (I have played around for a while). Very simple custom webpart can be developed.

Answer (score -2):

Easy. Edit/create a view to add 'Checked out to'. If not already there, also add 'Modified'. Sort by one or both.

Comment: Afraid that won't work. The modified date will show the checked out date to the user whom checked out the doc - but everyone else will see the old modified date.