# Get CheckedOutDate by using Web Services

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-services

I am able to find out whether the document in SharePoint document library is checked out or not by using SharePoint Webservice Lists.GetListItems() and from returned attribute "ows_CheckoutUser".

Is there any way I can find out the time when this document was checked out using SharePoint Webservices?

Comment: Related: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14030/document-library-show-checked-out-date-in-ui

Answer (score 1):

I guess no way available through OOTB. In case custom coding is allowed then you can write an event receiver to capture the check out action to update another field and later on use that information.